# Uploading a Excel Sheet in C# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

My code is

```
string PathConn = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox10.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

OleDbDataAdapter dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + textBox1.Text + "$]", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dbDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I get the error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line does this fail on?

Since you're taking parameters from text boxes, are you sure that you are getting the correct values?

Comment: when is the above code getting executed, are you executing it after getting proper value in textbox ? if you are doing it in page load it will not work as in that case the value in textbox will be empty.

Comment: this line dbDataAdapter.Fill(dt);  I think I get correct values.

Comment: Do you need the `$` to be part of the name of whatever it is you're selecting from?

Comment: Did you check the value of text box? Maybe, it's empty?

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be the "$"
in

```
("Select * From [" + textBox1.Text + "$]", conn);
```

Try

```
("Select * From "+ textBox1.Text , conn);
```

or

```
("Select * From ["+ textBox1.Text +"]", conn);
```

which looks like a more correct sql statement to me.

And if I might make a suggestion, try giving your text boxes names that mean more so that your code is more maintainable in the future.